# How to set name for select in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I'm currently looking through our Rails application to fix bugs. As a complete beginner, this portion:

```
    <%= fields_for live_result_log , :index =>live_result_log.id do |field|%>
    <%= field.select(:control_reason_id, ControlReason.where(:delete_flag=>0).collect{|i|[i.reason_name, i.id]},
    {:include_blank => false,:selected => live_result_log.control_reason_id}, :class => "select_result")  %>
    </td>
```

is giving me headaches. The use case is that there should be several live result log entries, and in this page several select objects are created depending on how may log entries there is. However, using firebug I was able to get the POST information (formatted for easy of reading):

```
&live_result_log%5Bcontrol_reason_id%5D=1
&live_result_log%5Bcontrol_reason_id%5D=1
&live_result_log%5Bcontrol_reason_id%5D=1
&live_result_log%5Bcontrol_reason_id%5D=1
&live_result_log%5Bcontrol_reason_id%5D=1
&live_result_log%5Bcontrol_reason_id%5D=4
&live_result_log%5Bcontrol_reason_id%5D=1
&live_result_log%5Bcontrol_reason_id%5D=1
&live_result_log%5Bcontrol_reason_id%5D=1
&live_result_log%5Bcontrol_reason_id%5D=1
&live_result_log%5Bcontrol_reason_id%5D=1
```

As you can see, the POST param is mostly identical, so when this is submitted, the control_reason_id becomes the same for all entries no matter what I choose, depending on the last item. How can I give the select different names so that I can differentiate between them?

The controller access the data using this:

```
@send_datas = params[:live_result_log][:control_reason_id]
```

The live_result_log is a model.

**EDIT**: So the plot thickens. In one version of the application, the rails version is 3.0.9, and the only difference is this part:

```
@send_datas = params[:live_result_log]["#{s}"][:control_reason_id]
```

and it works fine. The POST data becomes something like this:

```
&live_result_log%5B7321%5D%5Bcontrol_reason_id%5D=1
&live_result_log%5B7322%5D%5Bcontrol_reason_id%5D=3
&live_result_log%5B7323%5D%5Bcontrol_reason_id%5D=5
```

so that there's additional information to differentiate between the parameters.

The Rails version we use for the problematic version is 3.2.0.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use `options_for_select` to create the options html.

In your controller:

```
@select_options = ControlReason.where(:delete_flag=>0).collect{|i|[i.reason_name, i.id]}
```

In your template:

```
<%= field.select(:control_reason_id, options_for_select(@select_options, live_result_log.control_reason_id),
{:include_blank => false}, :class => "select_result")  %>
```

See the docs: [options_for_select](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html#method-i-options_for_select)

Comment: Tested it. The result is the same. There's still no differentiation between the select objects. Good refactoring though, I might keep it.

Answer (score 0):

[`collection_select`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/collection_select) might help:

```
<%= fields_for live_result_log , index: live_result_log.id do |field|%>
    <%= field.collection_select :control, :reason_id, ControlReason.where(delete_flag: 0), :id, :name %>
<% end %>
```

Although I'm probably wrong, as I don't know what you're trying to do with `live_result_log`.

Comment: live_result_log is a model I believe. I'll try if it helps.

Comment: Sure, just try it out. Maybe it will give you some more perspective!

Comment: It did not work, sadly. Please see my edit, I'm now thinking it might have something to do with the Rails version.